# Websocket certificate for local network

Tags: javascript, c#, flash, ssl, websocket

I am having trouble with certificate when using websocket (WSS://).

**What is working**
For now, I've been using websocket with `WEB_SOCKET_FORCE_FLASH = true` and I had no issues with connecting to my websocket server.

**What is not working**
I am trying to turn that option off, to stop using flash plugin for connecting. Problem occurs when i try to connect my websocket client to server. `WebSocket opening handshake was canceled` message appears.

I can disable this message, by going to https://127.0.0.1:9999. My browser will show that "This Connection is Untrusted", and if I add an exception here, my websocket connection will start working without any problem from now on. But i CAN'T make every end user to do that, right?
[Google groups with this idea](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sip_js/fry3eNVODo8)

**What I need?**
Is there any way, to buy, or create some self-signed certificate, which I can use? The problem is also that, it doesn't have to be localhost/127.0.0.1 but also any other IP in local network. (like `192.168.0.100` etc). End user can change that IP whenever he likes to. He just needs to point on the PC where my desktop app/websocket server is running.

**What have I tried?**
I sure tried to find my answer in google, browsing tons of forums, sites, and even few questions and all answers here on stack overflow.
I also tried not using certificate at all, but my page is on https:// so connection using ws:// is impossible.

**Code**
I know, code is usually obligatory, but I actually got my websocket client/server working, but the issue is certificate, so i hope you can forgive me lack of code.

**missing info?**
Do i need to provide any more information? I am willing to make multiple edits if needed.

Answer (score 0):

While the current certificate system is kind of broken it is fortunately not broken enough to allow what you want.  What you expect to get based on your description is a certificate for an IP addresses (bad idea anyway) which you don't even own fully (you cannot claim to be the owner of 127.0.0.1 or similar addresses) which then will be accepted by every browser without the need to add a manual exception by the user.